# Slackware64 Android Bundle Kit Segmentation fault

Tags: android, adb, fault, slackware

I had no problems installing the "android bundle kit" (eclipse + ADT) on Slackware64 14.0.

However, a lot of weird errors appeared with the project, and when trying to run after a lot of suffering, I receive a "Segmentation fault".

I thought that was an installation failure on my "multilib" and I reinstalled it, again.

"Segmentation fault" persisted when trying to run adb.

So, I remembered I have a functional skype installed in my linux.

Then, I changed all files on "/usr/lib" using the ones on skype directory.

Believe or not, now my android tools are working (fine!)

This is not a great solution, but I was desperate and this saved me.

What is the proper solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Then, I changed all files on "/usr/lib" using the ones on skype directory.

A segfault is just a crash.  You should have looked at the stacktrace to figure out exactly what library was at fault and tried updating that library (or searching the internet for help) rather than clobbering everything with your "skykpe libraries"

Given your approach, I suspect you have done more damage to your system than you realize.